# Error: Lapack library not found in compile time (zerobrane, lua, torch)

Tags: linux, lua, torch, openblas, zerobrane

After research I found:

```
git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
cd OpenBLAS
make NO_AFFINITY=1 USE_OPENMP=1
sudo make install
```

and

```
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/include:/opt/OpenBLAS/lib:$CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH luarocks install torch
```

which again left me with an error:

```
Makefile.system:370: *** OpenBLAS: 
Cannot set both USE_OPENMP=1 and USE_THREAD=0. 
The USE_THREAD=0 is only for building single thread version.. Stop.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the necessary change:

```
make NO_AFFINITY=1 USE_OPENMP=0 USE_THREAD=0
```

Might be an issue if only one core is available.